# CORS not working with Lambda Proxy with container runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to CORS to my lambda running in a docker image. I've added the headers to my lambda response like so

```
return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
            },
            "body": "testing"
        }
```

And enabled the Lambda Proxy Integration in API Gateway. When I hit the endpoint in PostMan, everything is returned exactly as expected for headers as you can see below.

[image]

However, when using with my application in chrome, I get the 403 forbidden and that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not present when seemingly it is. I've looked at many similar issues to this but none seem to resolve mine

Comment: Could you share the exact error response you get hitting the endpoint from the browser please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the pre flight request to the OPTIONS resource? You need to make sure the OPTIONS resource has the following response:

```
{
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": ["Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token"],
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": ["OPTIONS,POST"],
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"],
  "Content-Type":["application/json"]
}
```

I would configure the OPTIONS endpoint as a mock response in API Gateway so that it always returns the above. Then requests to your POST endpoint should work as expected from your browser.

Make sure you don't place any auth requirements on the OPTIONS resource.